# Magento tab ajax

Tags: ajax, magento

How magento tabed ajax work?lets take one example so we can understand better.at admin dashboard after page load once we click on the "Most Viewed Products" tab it will fire ajax once and then we check "bestseller" and again we click on "Most Viewed Products" at this time no ajax fire it give response from the cache i think. How does this happen in prototype ajax?[image]

Comment: I don't see any magic there. One First click we can addsome class to element(clicked). When you click again we can check element has clicked class. Then no need to call ajax(content already loaded)

Comment: Thanks for your replay..ohhh i see it's just added 'notloaded' class to unloaded tab..nothing else.